# Map Kit Bad Instruction Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit

I sent out a functioning test build of my app on to test flight. To remove some errors I did the following:

- Turned off device orientation left and right
- ticked requires full screen
- and finally, replaced the valid app icons.

However, I noticed my label and background was missing from this test build so I opened it up in the simulator and received this error:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

about the line:

```
 let distanceSpan:CLLocationDegrees = 2000
    MapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.0556253, 174.0752278), distanceSpan,distanceSpan), animated: true)
```

I have no idea what has caused this also in the output I got:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

but I don't see where the optional value is? I have attached my code [here](http://pastebin.com/FNH72gF0)

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: CCLocationDegrees is a latitude or longitude value specified in degrees. 2000 is not a latitude (+90 to -90) or a longitude (+180 to -180). Guessing this is causing distanceSpan to return with no value or more likely zero'?) hence the error when you try to use it in MapView.setRegion()

Comment: but isn't this just the area the map creates? It shouldn't have to be a latitude or longitude because the map has already been created around -39.0556253, 174.0752278 and this is just specifying the height and width of the map?

Comment: In this case, `distanceSpan` is a distance, measured in kilometers, so 2000, is perfectly valid. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/1452245-mkcoordinateregionmakewithdistan)

Comment: Although it should be `let distanceSpan : CLLocationDistance = 2000`

Comment: changed it to CLLocationDistance = 2000 but it is still giving me the same error. Its strange because it was working perfectly fine before. Could it be something to do with my storyboard?

Comment: I deleted my map view and then replaced it but the segue is still there so I don't think that would cause it. Other solutions show pins annotations being initialised BEFORE the map is created but I don't think this is the case for me plus I've had it working just before I published it to Test flight. Is there anyway for me to go back to a previous version?

Comment: Otherwise this is happening when its trying to get the users location?